# Find records based on id, compare date and update the one with the oldest date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, let's call it the UserTable.

[image]

What I would like to do is to:

- Find the duplicate UserID
- Compare the StartDate and update the record with the oldest StartDate by filling in the EndDate (current date minus 1)
- Do this for all duplicate records in the table

End result should look like:

[image]

I got it down to:

```
UPDATE UserTable
    SET EndDate = GETDATE()-1
WHERE EndDate IS NULL AND StartDate < (GETDATE()) AND
(UserID) in (
  select UserID 
  from   UserTable
  group  by UserID
  having count(*) > 1)
```

Only thing I can't figure out is how to update only the one with the oldest StartDate. Based on the code above, all records that are found are updated.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to them.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to update only that one record.  But, a convenient approach is to use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select ut.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by startdate) as seqnum
      from UserTable ut
     )
update toupdate
    set EndDate = dateadd(day, -1, getdate())
    where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: The reason I only want to update that record is because someone goes to a different team I need to know the period there where in the previous team. Tried your code but at this point it updates all other records instead of only that one.